# Remove button after it has been clicked?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, action

how would i get my program to work so that when a button is clicked it is removed?

here is the code:

```
//Mainmenu
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
Container pane = frame1.getContentPane();

JButton a = new JButton(new ImageIcon("path2img"));
BufferedImage a1 = ImageIO.read(new File("path2img"));

 public Menu() throws IOException {
     frame1.setSize(300, 450);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setResizable(false);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    pane.add(a);
    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aa) {
            pane.remove(a);

        }


    });
            }
```

thanks

Comment: Is setting the visibility to false in the action listener an option?

Comment: Did you try to hide it?

Comment: What about `(JButton)aa.getSource()).dispose()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you add or remove a component to something that's already displayed on the screen, you must call `(re)validate(); repaint();`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide it and make it not visible. You can set its visible property to false.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    a.setVisible(false);
}
```

Alternatively, repaint the panel holding the button after you remove it (if you really want to discard the button.)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    pane.remove(a);
    pane.repaint();
}
```